# Open netrw from the command line with a filtered list of files

Tags: vim, netrw

`vim .` lists the files in the current directory.

```
C:\temp> vim .
```

That results in this listing:

```
" ============================================================================
" Netrw Directory Listing                                        (netrw v156)
"   C:\temp
"   Sorted by      name
"   Sort sequence: [\/]$,\.h$,\.c$,\.cpp$,*,\.o$,\.obj$,\.info$,\.swp$,\.bak$,\~$
"   Quick Help: <F1>:help  -:go up dir  D:delete  R:rename  s:sort-by  x:special
" ==============================================================================
../
./
bar.md
bar.txt
baz.md
baz.txt
foo.md    
foo.txt
```

How do we open netrw from the command line with a filtered list of files?

We're looking for something like this:

```
C:\temp> vim . foo*
```

That results in this listing:

```
" ============================================================================
" Netrw Directory Listing                                        (netrw v156)
"   C:\temp
"   Sorted by      name
"   Sort sequence: [\/]$,\.h$,\.c$,\.cpp$,*,\.o$,\.obj$,\.info$,\.swp$,\.bak$,\~$
"   Quick Help: <F1>:help  -:go up dir  D:delete  R:rename  s:sort-by  x:special
" ==============================================================================
../
./
foo.md    
foo.txt
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The closest to this that I know netrw is capable of is hiding files by suffix, but I don't think that would do it for you.

Comment: @Amadan netrw can actually hide by regex, have a look at `g:netrw_list_hide` but that is still not suitable for the usecase. I would recommend to have a look at [FZF](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf)